# programs very slow to start in ubuntu

Tags: performance, cinnamon

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 + Cinnamon on my workstation.  The machine is old (probably 7+ years), but it is still an i7 with 24Gb of RAM.  I also have a GEForce 210 and I'm running the NVIDIA binary driver, version 340.98.

Starting up programs seems to take forever.  For example, I just started a UXTerm.  It took three seconds to draw the window, and 21 seconds (!) before I had a prompt that I could type at.  (Subsequent launches are quicker, on the order of 1 second to draw the window, and 8 seconds to get the prompt.)

Any thoughts on what I might be able to do to speed this stuff up?

Comment: Move your installation to a Solid State Drive.

Comment: Upgrade your video card

Comment: Boot to a live disc and see if the issue still occurs.